# SSIS Flat File connection manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis

I have an SSIS package that exports multiple SQL tables to CSV files. To do this I have a flat file destination and Flat file connection manager for each one.

The problem I am having is when I add a new column in one of the SQL tables i have to re create the Flat file connection manager for it to automatically pick up all the columns.

Does anybody know of a quicker way for the flat file to refresh the columns from SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately there is no easy way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jayvee, i thoght that might be the case. Are you aware of any add ins for SSIS that will help me do this?

Comment: I don't know about any add in ...what you can do is play around with information_schema.columns and concatenate all the columns in a comma-separated string, then dump it to flat files which will end up being the csvs you need... but if it's just to dump data out of sql server you might be better off using BCP.

Comment: You could use BCP.EXE instead of SSIS (more info here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx) and dynamically create the format file. Here is a complex (but complete) example of a stored procedure that creates a format file for you. http://www.chilledsql.com/welcome/tip_category_archiving/tip_detail_archiving_dynamicbcpformafile